# Release Management and Distributing regular updates

Tags: provisioning, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a .NET application that I am distributing regularly through an .exe and .exe.config.   Rather than sending around the executable to team members every time there is an update (which is often), is there any way to check for updates when they launch the app? I see this in most Desktop applications but not sure how it's done. Can I integrate with our VS Team Services repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTS can’t check updates when the app is launching. But you can use VSTS [**CI** ( continuous integration) build and **CD** (continuous deployment) release](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/aspnet-4-ci-cd-vs-automatic) to update the app before it launching.

Detail steps as below:

1. Push your code in VSTS repo (Git or TFVC).

   Such as you can create a git repo on VSTS, and then [clone/commit/push](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart) changes to the remote repo.
2. Add a CI build for your project.

   You can use ASP.NET template or add tasks manually to define what you want to build. For Triggers, you can trigger the CI build when changes are pushed in your repo, or you can use schedule trigger to build your code for certain time specified.

   [image]
3. Trigger release by CD so that the latest app is deployed to the machine(s) you use.

   Add a release with your build definition and CD selected. Then add the tasks you need to deploy.

Comment: Can this be used for standalone exes? The documentation only refers to Web Apps in Azure

Comment: Yes, you can deploy other kinds of app to other machines or environments. The document above explain how CI build and CD release works.